# How to map to a Dictionary object from database results using Dapper Dot Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

If I have a simple query such as:

```
string sql = "SELECT UniqueString, ID  FROM Table";
```

and I want to map it to a dictionary object such as:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

How would I do this with Dapper?

I assume it is something like:

```
myDictionary = conn.Query<string, int>(sql, new {  }).ToDictionary();
```

But can't figure out the proper syntax.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There's various ways already shown; personally I'd just use the non-generic api:

```
var dict = conn.Query(sql, args).ToDictionary(
    row => (string)row.UniqueString,
    row => (int)row.Id);
```

Comment: I didn't even realize you could leave out the return type in the query method.

Comment: FYI. Those property names for the fields being returned are case sensitive. In Oracle the fields being returned to me were in all capital letters so for example row.UniqueString was coming back from Oracle as row.UNIQUESTRING.

Comment: @Colin since other RDBMS allow for case sensitive names (so .foo, .FOO and .Foo are all different) I am not sure I can do much about that, other than to say "expect whatever your RDBMS returns"

Comment: Works well, but this solution uses dynamic objects, which I try to avoid, if possible. Check out Allen.Cais solution, without dynamic objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815558/4249619

Comment: @andreas it is the same object either way. The fact that it happens to implement the interfaces necessary for dynamic to work is separate

Answer (score 40):

```
string strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT TableID AS [Key],TableName AS [Value] FROM dbo.TS_TStuctMaster";
Dictionary<string,string> dicts = sqlConnection.Query<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(strSql).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

You can use aliases and strong types.

**Aliases are the key points, which match the attributes of KeyValuePair type Key and Value.**

It works under strong typing and runs well.

*I don't like dynamic type. It brings disaster in certain situations. Moreover, the boxing and unboxing brings performance loss.*

Comment: Thanks, that's the shortest and easiest solution while still using strong typing. I guess the accepted answer with dynamic typing runs much slower.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using > .net 4.7 or netstandard2 you can use value tuples. the code is nice and terse and there is no use of dynamics.

```cs
var sql = "SELECT UniqueString, Id  FROM Table";
var dict = conn.Query<(string UniqueString, int Id)>(sql)
           .ToDictionary(t => t.UniqueString,t => t.Id);
```

Answer (score 20):

Works also without an additional class:

```
var myDictionary = conn.Query<string, int, KeyValuePair<string,int>>(sql, (s,i) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(s,i))
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

**NOTE**: When using Dapper.NET 3.5 version, the Query method that takes the first, second and return types requires you specify more parameters, as the .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 versions take advantage of [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

In this case, the following code should work:

```
string splitOn = "TheNameOfTheValueColumn";
var myDictionary = conn.Query<string, int, KeyValuePair<string,int>>(sql, (s,i) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(s,i), null, null, false, splitOn, null, null)
        .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Most of the arguments will revert to a default, but `splitOn` is required, as it will otherwise default to a value of 'id'.

For a query that returns two columns, '*ID*' and '*Description*', `splitOn` should be set to '*Description*'.

Comment: Tim - Your solution is completely valid, but I prefer Marc's for simplicity sake.

Comment: Can you explain *Works also without an additional class* are you implying I need a class for [Marcs solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14786328/542251)? Neither really explains this

Comment: @Liam: i think i was referring to [w.brian's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14781485/284240) approach.

Comment: Ah OK. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 14):

Dapper also has an extension method for `ExecuteReader`.  So, you could also do this:

```
var sql = "SELECT UniqueString, ID  FROM Table";
var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
using (var reader = cn.ExecuteReader(sql)) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
            dict[reader.GetName(i)] = reader.GetInt32(i);
        }
        rows.Add(dict);
    }
}
```

This approach works without knowing the column names.  Moreover, if you don't know the data types, you could change `Dictionary<string,int>` to `Dictionary<string,object>` and `GetInt32(i)` to `GetValue(i)`.

Comment: beautiful solution, just what I was searching for. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is possible.  If you define a class to map the query to this becomes far more trivial:

```
public class MyRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UniqueString { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you would just do this:

```
var sql = "SELECT UniqueString, ID  FROM Table";
var myDictionary = conn.Query<MyRow>(sql).ToDictionary(row => row.UniqueString, row => row.Id);
```

Answer (score 4):

For the table of which you do not know the structure at runtime

```
    using var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    var sql = $"Select * From {tableName} Order By {primaryKey}";

    var result = await db.QueryAsync(sql); 
    return result
        .Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>()
        .Select(it => it.ToDictionary(it => it.Key, it => it.Value));
```

Comment: +1 this is answer is good because internal DappeRow class implements IDictionary<string, object>> already :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use like this (1 liner):

```
var dict = dapper.Query<(string, int)>(sql).ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, row => row.Item2);
```