# Dapper.net use query into the Dictionary

Tags: c#, dapper

my sql is :

```
select (select count(*) from TblRMember where sex=1) male,
 (select count(*) from TblRMember where sex=2) female,
 (select count(*) from TblRMember where sex=0) unkown
```

I want Dapper.Net to return a Dictinary like this:

```
Keys:male,female,nukown
Value:10,30,50
```

I have see [How to map to a Dictionary object from database results using Dapper Dot Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780767/how-to-map-to-a-dictionary-object-from-database-results-using-dapper-dot-net) ,but that can not work!

How to use ToDictionary or other way to implement I want

```
var myDictionary = sqlConnection.Query(strSql).ToDictionary(??);
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does that SQL work?

Comment: @shahkalpesh in mysql,the column is male,femail,unkown ,like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First change your query to be single one:

```
select case when sex = 1 then 'male'
            when sex = 2 then 'female'
            when sex = 0 then 'unknown'
       end as sex, count(*) as cnt
from TblRMember
group by sex
```

as I see `sex` is numerical, so you either have to select by coumn with name (sexname?) or change it in your code. After that:

```
var myDictionary = sqlConnection.Query(strSql)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.sex.ToString(), x => (int)x.cnt);
```

Comment: ,thanks~~ I'm stupid ~ ~ this solution is very easy!!!I also want to know, my SQL can be implemented?

Comment: @gzaxx: Please add the clause that makes the numeric value of sex, into key such as Male/Female/Unknown. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
string strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT TableID AS [Key],TableName AS [Value] FROM dbo.TS_TStuctMaster";
Dictionary<string,string> dicts = sqlConnection.Query<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(strSql).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

You can use aliases and strong types.

**Aliases are the key points, which match the attributes of KeyValuePair type Key and Value.**

It works under strong typing and runs well.

*I don't like dynamic type. It brings disaster in certain situations. Moreover, the boxing and unboxing brings performance loss.*